# What is wrong with the following query?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I have a table containing name, surname and email. I want to retrieve them from the table and so i write:

```
if (LoginAs.SelectedValue == "Administrator")
{
    string result;
    string query = "Select * from AdminTable where ID='"+ idBox.Text +"'";
    cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    result = Convert.ToString(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());

    Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
    //Admin user = new Admin(idBox.Text, "Active",  mail, firstName, LastName, passwordBox.Text);
}
```

The problem is, it only returns the name field of the specified row even though i wrote "Select *". What is wrong here?

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns just the first column of the first row, and ignores the rest.

Comment: @HansKesting so what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns just the first column of the first row, and ignores the rest.

So you should use [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) method. An example from MSDN:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
    }
}
```

Note that the `while (reader.Read())` checks whether your query returned (more) results and positions the cursor on the next record, that you can then read. This example prints the first column's value.
The `using` statement makes sure the connection is closed after use, whatever happens.

Also, don't build your query directly with input from the user (such as the value of a TextBox), use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

You must try `ExecuteReader()` instead of using `ExecuteScalar()`

ExecuteScaler is used in situation where we have to read a single value.eg:

> select count(*) from tablename.

while

> ExecuteReader is used for any result set with multiple rows/columns
>   (e.g., SELECT * from TableName)

Comment: I do it but where does it return the result? how can i get it as a string

Comment: do'nt execute reader against a String.
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: if(dr.HasRows)
{
string result="";
   while(dr.Read)
    {
      result =Convert.ToString(dr["FieldNameInDatabase"]);
    }
return result;

Answer (score 2):

Sample code:

```
 string myQuery="Select * from AdminTable where ID=@myid";
 SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(myQuery,conn);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myid", value);
 conn.Open();
 SqlDataReader dreader;
 dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
 while (dreader.Read())
 {
    string Value1= dreader["COl1"].ToString();
    string Value2= dreader["COl2"].ToString();
 }  
 dreader.Close();
```

Always use parameterized Query

Answer (score 1):

You may try `cmd1.ExecuteReader()` instead.